# Issue when publishing a post with Iron Router

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I want to create a route where I'm able to reply to comments (.../comments/:_id/reply), but I'm having problems in publishing the post related with the comment.

Here is the code:

Publications

```
Meteor.publish('commentUser', function(commentId) {
    var comment = Comments.findOne(commentId);
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: comment && comment.userId});
});

Meteor.publish('commentPost', function(commentId) {
    var comment = Comments.findOne(commentId);
    return Posts.find({_id: comment && comment.postId});
});

Meteor.publish('singleComment', function(commentId) {
    return Comments.find(commentId);
});
```

Route

```
this.route('comment_reply', {
    path: '/comments/:_id/reply',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('singleComment', this.params._id),
            Meteor.subscribe('commentUser', this.params._id),
            Meteor.subscribe('commentPost', this.params._id)
        ]
    },
    data: function() {
            return {
                comment: Comments.findOne(this.params._id)
            }
    }

 });
```

Comment Reply Template

```
<template name="comment_reply">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
         {{# with post}}
              {{> postItem}}
         {{/with}}
    </div>

    <div class="small-12 columns">
          {{#with comment}}
          {{> comment}}
      {{/with}}
     </div>

     {{> commentReplySubmit}}   

</template>
```

Comment Reply Helper

```
Template.comment_reply.helpers({
     postItem: function() {
         return Posts.findOne(this.comment.postId);
     }
});
```

When I access that route, the {{#with comment}} renders properly but the {{#with post}} doesn't appears. And if I try to render only {{> postItem}} without {{#with post}} it renders the html, but without the data.

The console prints this alert: You called Route.prototype.resolve with a missing parameter. "_id" not found in params

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mixed up the names of your template `post` (code is not given though) and your template helper `postItem`.

```
      {{#with post}}
          {{> postItem}}
      {{/with}}
```

Should probably be

```
      {{#with postItem}}
          {{> post}}
      {{/with}}
```

Or do you have a template and a template helper called `postItem`?

Also there is a space between `#` and `with`, I am not sure if that is allowed.

**Alternatively**

```
Template.comment_reply.helpers({
     postItem: function() {
         return Posts.findOne(this.comment.postId);
     }
});
```

should be

```
Template.comment_reply.helpers({
     post: function() {
         return Posts.findOne(this.comment.postId);
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was related with the template helper

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you try to break apart the template into smaller templates? If I'm not mistaken, I don't think you can have multiple data context unless it has the same _Id. In this  case, the post and the comment _Id will be different and would throw and error like the one you're getting. Try something like this:

```
<template name="comment_reply">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
         {{# with post}}
              {{> postItem}}
         {{/with}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="postItem">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      {{#with comment}}
          {{> comment}}
      {{/with}}
     </div>
</template> 

<template name="comment">
     {{> commentReplySubmit}}   
</template>
```

You'll likely have to play around with the syntax of the templates and the routing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but the problem was related with the function inside the template helper.

Comment: Not a problem! Glad you got it fixed :)